# Blender extrude along normals

Tags: edit-mode, faces, extrude

Hello I am new ot Blender. So even when i am choosing "Extrude faces along normals". Getting this result. It isnot filling gaps of corners. How can i fix that?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What you've done looks more like an alt E > Extrude Individual Faces than an E (simple extrude). If you select the whole ring of faces, make a simple E, then S + shift Z to scale on X and Y axis, you should get what you want, no?

Answer (score 2):

What you've done looks more like an <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Individual Faces* than an <kbd>E</kbd> (simple extrude). If you select the whole ring of faces, make a simple <kbd>E</kbd>, then <kbd>S</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to scale on X and Y axis, you should get what you want.